# Angular: Flex-Layout why are my <div>s not even in width and fxLayoutAlign not working?

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I've got an array of 3 elements composed of a title and its respective content. 
I'm trying to loop over the array to yield a list of s in the DOM which would idealy be the same width and spaced evenly between one another.

So here's my TS with the array:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  list= [
    {title: 'T1 - Lorem ipsum, this a test, just a test', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'},
    {title: 'T2 - Lorem ipsum, this a test, just a test', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'},
    {title: 'T3 - Lorem ipsum, this a test, just a test', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'},
  ];
}
```

and the corresponding HTML file:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly">
  <div *ngFor="let el of list">
    <div class="title">{{ el.title }}</div>
    <div class="content">{{ el.content }}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly">
  <div style="background-color: orange">Test1</div>
  <div style="background-color: lightgreen">Test2</div>
  <div style="background-color: lightblue">Test3</div>
</div>
```

For the sake of the example, you'll see that I have a layed out a second section where there's an example of a list of `<div>`s properly even in width and evenly spaced in the HTML (section with Test1, 2 and 3).

You'll find a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3u4sep

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want different sized children to have the same width, you have to set the same grow property to all of them. You can do this by adding `fxFlex="1"` (or just `fxFlex`) to the divs:

```
<div *ngFor="let el of list" fxFlex>
  <div class="title">{{ el.title }}</div>
  <div class="content">{{ el.content }}</div>
</div>
```

Now all divs have the same grow (and shrink) ratio, so the width will be evenly shared. More info on the `fxFlex` attribute [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API).

Your "TestN" texts have the same width, that's why they're even.

Comment: Thanks Parziphal! What about the `fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly"` that don't work?

Comment: Oh yeah... turns out `space-evenly` and other values work with the free space left after placing the children, but in this case there's no space left. I'd recommend understanding Flexbox first (in pure CSS), then understand this or any other flexbox library. Any doubt like this should be checked with the behaviour of Flexbox instead of the behaviour of the library (this is what I do).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Parziphal

Answer (score 2):

As the content is not the same length for each array element, it takes space according to its content length. Add `fxFlex` to the child `div`s and it should work.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around">
  <div *ngFor="let el of list" fxFlex>
    <div class="title">{{ el.title }}</div>
    <div class="content">{{ el.content }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```